# Gitlab-ce backup restore failing for certain repos

Tags: gitlab, rake, gitlab-ce

I'm trying to set up a perpetually 1 day old clone of a gitlab server.  The gitlab version on both machines 12.4.1-ce.0. There's a daily crontab for the following:

```
gitlab-rake GZIP_RSYNCABLE=yes gitlab:backup:create
```

Then it transfers the backup to my clone machine and it runs

```
gitlab-ctl stop unicorn && gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq && gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=most_recent force=yes --trace && gitlab-ctl restart
```

All of the infrastructure there works and I'm happy with it, but then during the restore, many many repos are failing to restore, throwing one of two messages for one of two types of restores:

1. repos larger than ~800MB

> Error: 4:Deadline Exceeded

2. all wikis

> Error 13:CreateRepositoryFromBundle: cmd wait failed: exit status 128

Searching around online said that this is probably a gitaly timeout issue, so I changed the default timeout from 55s to 475s, the fast from 10s to 30s, and the medium from 30s to 115s, but that made no difference.

At the end of the restore, I get this message:

```
2019-11-20 12:46:14 -0500 -- Restoring lfs objects ... 
2019-11-20 12:46:14 -0500 -- done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:registry:restore (first_time)
** Invoke gitlab_environment
** Execute gitlab:backup:registry:restore
2019-11-20 12:46:14 -0500 -- Restoring container registry images ... 
rake aborted!
Backup::Error: Backup failed
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/files.rb:81:in `run_pipeline!'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/files.rb:44:in `restore'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:234:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:71:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:registry:restore
```

I'm not even sure if that's because of the same problem, or if it's entirely unrelated. Anyone know what's wrong, or where I can start looking next?